# Random segmentation fault from printf(), can someone help explain?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

I have a piece of code that gets a number from the user, and then allocates an integer array of the given size. However it seg faults on numbers as big as 5,000,000. Here it is:

```
#define LINELEN 32

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n;

    char buffer[LINELEN];
    fprintf (stderr, "n? ");
    fgets (buffer, LINELEN, stdin);
    n = atoi(buffer);       

    int vector [n];
    printf("hi\n");
}
```

I deduce that the printf is causing the seg fault because this code runs fine for huge numbers:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n;

    char buffer[LINELEN];
    fprintf (stderr, "n? ");
    fgets (buffer, LINELEN, stdin);
    n = atoi(buffer);       

    int vector [n];

}
```

Can someone please help me? Thank you

edit: LINELEN, and erroneous printf argument

also, I think it has something to do with the value overflowing the stack. May just have to dynamically allocate at those sizes

Comment: share the value of `LINELEN`

Comment: Why do you have a 0 as an argument? You can just print the string by itself. Otherwise, it needs to be a part of your format string. `printf("hi\n");
printf("hi\n%d", 0);` I doubt this is the cause of the seg fault, though.

Comment: @remyabel, I guess there is no problem with `printf("hi\n",0);`. If any format specified is mentioned, then it will cause seg fault.

Comment: why do you need to allocate such large arrays? 5000000 ints are ~20MB. Normal stacks are about 1-10MB

Comment: fgets appends a '\n'at the end of the string are you negating it before atoi ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The segmentation fault is caused by [stack overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Very_large_stack_variables) because `int vector [5000000];` is too big for the stack.

When the `printf` line is not there, probably the compiler optimized the line `int vector [n];` since it's the end of the program.

Comment: Ok that's what I suspected. I'll just dynamically allocate it then. Thanks